# Reg:python 3 why do we have to provide reference variable for functions to output

Tags: python, python-3.x

if i wrote a code like below

```
 case 1:
    def add(x,y):
        return x+y
    
    add(10,20)
```

after execution in powershell nothing gets printed on the output window(powershell) but if i use this

```
case 2:
    def add(x,y):
        return x+y
    
    result=add(10,20)
    print(result)
```

it does print 30 in output(powershell)so my question is why do we need to use ref variable `result` to print the output why cant we directly print like in case 1

Thank you

Comment: Case 1 isn't printing anything though. You don't need `result` : you could do `print(add(10,20))`

Comment: yeah i have tried that it does give output but i am curious about why do we need ref variable why cant we print directly?

Comment: As stated, you don't need it! If you ran this in the python REPL it would give you the result, but python code isn't a REPL. `add(10,20)` is actually a totally useless line becuase you don't store the result for use, or do anything at all with it.

Comment: You don't *need* the variable, you ca do `print(add(10, 20))` if you want. But *you have to `print`* for your program to print something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need the reference variable. `print(add(10,20))` will work as well.  you need `print` to send output to your terminal.  (a jupyter notbooks works differently)